# How do we count views on question-threads?

Tags: support

When I see that a question has 1067 views, is that 1067 separate people, or maybe 45 people many times?  Or maybe even 1 view per person per day is counted.  What does the 'views' number mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) has answered this:

> The view count is not increased for the same IP address, within certain thresholds.
>
> However, if you visit a question 1 day later, the count will probably increase, even if we saw the IP before.
>
> Tracking IP lists per question would be a bit on the expensive side.
>
> <sup><sub>[Does the number of times viewed track unique ips?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74920/does-the-number-of-time-viewed-track-unique-ips/74921#74921)</sub></sup>

Comment: Probably?  Or definitely?  So was my guess right, in my question?  1 view per person per day is counted?

Comment: @drm if I had to guess I'd say that in that context "probably" means some combination of "it's more complicated actually, but this is close enough" and "it might change later and I don't want to be held to this"

Comment: @Pat: Fair enough!